# how to change plotting time series axes to show time instead of date

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the script below, I m trying to change my plot to show hours instead of month and year on the bottom.

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(10)]
y = ['54.2', '54.8', '54.2', '54.8', '55.3', '55.3', '55.3', '55.3', '54.8', '54.8']
# plot
plt.plot(x,y)
# beautify the x-labels
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

print(x)
print(y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting `set_major_formatter` format:

### Approach 1

By changing x axis format directly. But, matplotlib will show only time in hh:00:00 format by default.

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates

x = [datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(10)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
y = ['54.2', '54.8', '54.2', '54.8', '55.3', '55.3', '55.3', '55.3', '54.8', '54.8']
# plot
plt.plot(x,y)
# beautify the x-labels
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
## create x-axis hour format
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter("%H:%M"))

plt.show()
```

### Approach 2

You can change x axis label value directly using `set_xticklabels` method. Just add the below code

```
plt.plot(x,y)
# beautify the x-labels
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
## create x-axis hour format
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter("%H:%M"))
x_hours = [date_str.strftime("%H:%M:%S") for date_str in x]
ax.set_xticklabels(x_hours)
plt.show
```

Comment: @Zargaf can you import `from matplotlib import dates`. I have updated in the solution

Comment: @Zargaf if my solution worked, can you upvote as well. Thanks

Comment: working now but it show (12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19) I m not sure what that represent

Comment: It is Hours representation, Can you tell me what format do you want exaclty?. You wanted `hours` format right. So you change the format as `dates.DateFormatter("%H:%m")`.

Comment: sorry I meant I need it to be current time so ("%H:%m") but not giving current time.

Comment: Sure. Let me change the format and update the solution.

Comment: `dates.DateFormatter("%H:%M")` format shows hours in matplotlib. Hope it solved your question. if yes, Don't hesitate to mark my solution as correct answer. Thanks

Comment: it still not displaying current time but it was close enough. I will mark it as true, if you have time I would appreciate if you help me make it current time.

Comment: @Zargaf Thanks. I added the x-axis label value as an exact hour format.